# Replace some chars from a String from performance perspective

Tags: java, string

I need to replace all the "\n#" or "\n\r#" with "chr(35)" in some string, so what is the best way to do this considering the performance issues ?

I have tried this, but i think its not good enough !!!

```
public String encodeHash(String data){

    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();

    int numberOfReplacedChars = 0;

    String hashPattern1 = "\n#" ;
    String hashPattern2 = "\n\r#" ;

    int index = data.indexOf(hashPattern1);

    if(index != -1 ){
        numberOfReplacedChars = hashPattern1.length();
    }else{
        index = data.indexOf(hashPattern2);
        if(index != -1){
            numberOfReplacedChars = hashPattern2.length() ;
        }else{
            return data;
        }
    }

    result.append(data.substring(0,index + (numberOfReplacedChars - 1)));
    result.append("chr(35)");
    // method call itself (recursive)
    result.append(encodeHash(data.substring(index + numberOfReplacedChars)));

    return result.toString();   
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything at all to solve this?

Comment: What kind of performance issues are you having?

Comment: please, provide with the 'low-performance' way that you have tried.

Comment: actually i need the fastest way to do this, because this code is looping throw millions of Strings, we talk here about 20 millions String in average, thanks.

Comment: [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) may help you more.

Comment: If you're looking for performance then keep static strings out of method `encodeHash` and make them `final static`.

Comment: If you're looking for performance: 1. Use `StringBuilder` instead of `StringBuffer`. 2. Use iteration instead of recursion. 3. Use better indexing (add a `beginIndex` variable) instead of creating substring.

Comment: Please don't use StringBuffer, StringBuilder has been provided as a recommended drop in replacement for nine years and StringBuffer was never a good idea IMHO http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2013/04/why-synchronized-stringbuffer-was-never.html

Comment: yea got it, no StringBuffer any more, thanks guys.

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
str = str.replaceAll("\n\r?#", "chr(35)");
```

If you're going to be doing this operation a lot, precompile the regex using a [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

It's difficult to say if this would perform better than two literal replaces, so if this is *really* a bottleneck for you then you should time both variants with some sample strings. In most contexts the performance difference would be completely negligible. Here is the alternative:

```
str = str.replace("\n#", "chr(35)").replace("\n\r#", "chr(35)");
```

Comment: I think its the fastest way, too. Our Java-Professor said in course that everytime he writes methods which existing in java the java standard implementation is faster then his...

Comment: @Kingalione Yes, an unbelievable amount of thought has gone in to fine-tuning those methods.

Comment: yea i have tried this before, but it's not working, i mean it replace nothing.

Comment: @JUBA Do you want to want to replace *literal* `\n\r`s or actual newline characters?

Comment: @arshajii, about the Patter thing, is not it harm to create an Patter and Matcher object for like 20 million times ??

Comment: @JUBA You should only need *one* `Pattern` holding the regex `\n\r?#`. You can create a lot of `Matcher`s, yes. In fact, that's what `str.replaceAll()` does behind the scenes each time you call it.

Comment: @arshajii not literal, i need to replace the # that preceded by newline

Comment: @JUBA Can you provide a simple test string for which this doesn't work?

Comment: I have tried this :    String data = "DATA\n\r#\n# :\n\r# #@\n\r#\n##DATA  \n\r#DATA";

but after i did this :
    data.replaceAll("\n\r#", " chr(35) ");

it just print this :
    DATA

#
# :

# #@

#
##DATA  

#DATA

Comment: @JUBA Strings are immutable, so you have to reassign `data` (like I did in the answer): `data = data.replaceAll(...)`. Also, don't forget the `?` after `\r`.

Answer (score 0):

@arshajii answer is correct. But another way you can try is to scan each char in string and just do StringBuilder#append.